# Variable '<variablename>' hides a variable in an enclosing block

Tags: .net, vb.net, syntax-error

When copying and pasting a bit of sample code from MSDN, I came up with the error in the title - [Variable '' hides a variable in an enclosing block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtk40des(VS.80).aspx),

All I copied was a very basic example of a try loop.

As it says in the suggestion "A common cause for this error is the use of Catch e As Exception inside an event handler. If this is the case, name the Catch block variable ex rather than e."

So, I did that, changed both `e` to `ex` and it worked, however, I don't understand why this doesn't cause the same error.

Can someone please explain better what the error is and why e causes it, and ex doesn't?

edit -

code example...

```
    Try
    Catch e As Exception
        msgbox(e.Message)
    End Try
```

.

```
    Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        msgbox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

What I don't understand is why the first one causes the problem and the second one doesn't, to me, it is like... Using apples above, apple below - saying you can't use the same thing in both places, then changing both to oranges and suddenly letting it work. Surely the second is doing the same as the first.

Comment: The code in question would help.

Comment: @Oded, I wanted a general overview, but added a brief example anyway.

Comment: You really should post the whole method where the error occurs. That small snippet doesn't say much. I assume there is either an `e` parameter (for instance, in an event handler the EventArgs are usually passed in with an e parameter name), or variable in the method elsewhere.

Comment: @Oded, no other code needed - If you just create a new VB.Net project with a Windows form, do anything - add a button and do that code, it will cause the problem. There isn't any other code using e - which is why I am having problems understanding this error.

Comment: @Wil: There is almost certainly code doing that. I've posted in my answer what I think is going to be going in when you create that event handler. Mine was from a ASP.NET project but I'll be very surprised if its not the exact same thing.

Comment: @Wil - take a look at the method you are pasting the code into. Any parameters passed into it? Mostly, Form_Load will have these parameters `(object sender, EventArgs e)` - see the `e` parameter? This is the one your Exception `e` is having an issue with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might want to paste the full code for the error to confirm but I would assume that the event handler defines a parameter called "e". Then when you put in the catch block it tries to define "e" as well, causing the error in question. Of course when the catch is defining "ex" instead of "e" then there is no name clash happening so it works.

**Edit:** Edited to add clearer example of what I assume is the breoken code.

I assume your breaking code looks like:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
    Catch e As Exception
        msgbox(e.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

You can see the two declarations of e, one in `ByVal e As System.EventArgs` and the other at `Catch e As Exception`.

Comment: +1 - Many thanks and marking as answer... Brilliant, Seems so easy now and I can't believe I missed this! This is exactly what it is!... Seems so simple now!

Comment: This is why its always worthwhile pasting full code. You might not think its necessary but you also don't know what's wrong so other people asking for it is generally at least worth asking "Which bit in particular" (if you think there is too much to paste it all). And thanks for getting me past 1k rep. ;-)

Answer (score 9):

That error message means that you are declaring a variable with a name that already exists:

```
int abc = 0;
if (abc == 0)  {
  int abc = 1;  // Error
}
```

This rule applies of course to try .. catch as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. rename the variable causing the problem to a unique name.